# Axios: unexpected end of stream

Tags: react-native, axios

I received the following error in fetching large amount of data(JSON) using axios in react native.

**Error: unexpected end of stream**

Here is my code:

```
axios.post('http://192.168.0.1:5000/download', {
      access: data.tokens
    })
    .then(function (response) {
       alert(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert("There was an error in communicating to server");
});
```

I tried to limit the result returned by the REST API (100 rows) and it returned some data.

How can I fetch large amount of data in Axios?

Comment: headers: {
   "Connection": "close"
 }

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Same error appeared

Comment: post your error also.

Comment: axios only returned the error: unexpected end of stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the default timeout for axios request is set to 0. I solved the problem by adding `timeout` into the axios configuration.

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      timeout: 1000,
      url: 'http://192.168.0.1:5000/download',
      data: {
        access: data.token
      }
    })
.then(function (response) {
   alert(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  alert("There was an error in communicating to server");
});
```

for some reason, `timeout` parameter will not work if placed after the `data` parameter

Comment: Hi @pikanerd, upvoted and my doubt is I am using inline shorter syntax for axios as: `axios.post('url' + data)`. How can I add timeout here? please tell.

Comment: maybe something like this? axios.post('http://sample-site', {data: id: '1'}, timeout: 1000)